# Ruby On Rails Paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, path

I am having trouble with paths in ruby on rails

My Routes:

```
    map.resources :companies do |company|
  company.resources :customers do |customer|
   customer.resources :jobs 
  end
  end
```

Currently I am creating the paths by hand:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', "/companies/#{params[:company_id]}/users/#{user.id}" %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', "/companies/#{params[:company_id]}/users/#{user.id}/edit" %></td>
```

For some reason I cant figure out how to get new_company_user to work I keep getting errors.

The routes are all there I just need help with dynamically creating them by using the API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to use `new_company_user` then you'd want something like this:

```
map.resources :companies do |company|
  company.resources :users do |user|
    user.resources :jobs 
  end
end
```

Comment: No problem, sometimes all it takes is an extra set of eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run `rake routes` from the command line and it will print a list of all routes generated from `routes.rb`, including named routes, the URL and HTTP request type that trigger them, and which controller action they run.

Comment: I did the rake and could see the route and could even write it out by hand but I couldnt figure out how to API. I figured out my problem was that I didnt add the right params in the path edit_company_user_path(params[:company_id],user) is working. Thanks for your help guys.